# backend multi-threading in PHP 7 (Symfony4)

Tags: php, multithreading, symfony, php-7, symfony4

(I read other questions, but they refer to older versions of PHP or frontend multi-threading)

I have a PHP/PostgreSQL application that has a complex backend processing part. Essentially, there is a very large loop (several thousand iterations) going over the same data again and again (with permutations). In each loop, the same data is read, operations are applied, the result is written back to the database. The loops are entirely independent from each other, no results are kept between loops. In fact, to clear the object cache memory (using Doctrine), I clear out the cache every 100 or so loops.

So I essentially have:

```
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
   // fetch data
   // manipulate data
   // write results to a different table
}
```

The original data is never touched during these loops, only several results tables are populated.

This currently takes several minutes. I seems to me like a textbook example of parallel processing.

What is the best way to put this into multiple threats? I don't care much about execution order or even if the workload is distributed evenly (by nature of the data operations, if all threads run the same number of loops, they should end up with more or less the same workload). All I want is to use more of my CPU cores.

I've done multi-threading in PHP 5 and it was... well... not perfect. Workable, but difficult. Has this improved in PHP 7 ? Is there a relatively simple way to basically say "for (...) and run it in n threads" ?

In case it matters, the app is written in Symfony4 and this backend process is called via a console command.

Comment: Take a look at this article https://medium.com/@rossbulat/true-php7-multi-threading-how-to-rebuild-php-and-use-pthreads-bed4243c0561

Comment: How about something as simple as a bash shell spawning multiple processes? (or GNU parallel.)

Comment: @Progrock that is an alternative, but I might want to later add an option to trigger the backend script from the frontent, with progress updates, etc.

Comment: found this today https://github.com/webmozarts/console-parallelization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) extension that is rewritten to be much simpler in use in v3. It is supported on PHP 7.2+ and provides a way to create multi-threaded applications in PHP.

Alternatively since you're using Symfony - you can write simple console command that can use [`Process`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) component to run sub-processes as separate OS processes. Here is example of such runner from actual project:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use App\Command\Exception\StopCommandException;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\LockableTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Webmozart\PathUtil\Path;

class ProcessingRunner extends AbstractCommand
{
    use LockableTrait;
    /**
     * @var Process[]
     */
    private $processes = [];
    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $cmd;
    /**
     * @var KernelInterface
     */
    private $kernel;

    /**
     * @param KernelInterface $kernel
     */
    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:processing:runner')
            ->setDescription('Run processing into multiple threads')
            ->addOption('threads', 't', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Number of threads to run at once', 1)
            ->addOption('at-once', 'm', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Amount of items to process at once', 10);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\LogicException
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws RuntimeException
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \LogicException
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): ?int
    {
        if (!$this->lock()) {
            $output->writeln('The command is already running in another process.');
            return 0;
        }
        if (extension_loaded('pcntl')) {
            $stop = function () {
                StopCommandException::throw();
            };
            pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, $stop);
            pcntl_signal(SIGINT, $stop);
            pcntl_async_signals(true);
        }
        do {
            try {
                while (\count($this->processes) < $this->getInput()->getOption('threads')) {
                    $process = $this->createProcess();
                    $process->start();
                    $this->processes[] = $process;
                }
                $this->processes = array_filter($this->processes, function (Process $p) {
                    return $p->isRunning();
                });
                usleep(1000);
            } catch (StopCommandException $e) {
                try {
                    defined('SIGKILL') || define('SIGKILL', 9);
                    array_map(function (Process $p) {
                        $p->signal(SIGKILL);
                    }, $this->processes);
                } catch (\Throwable $e) {

                }
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        $this->release();
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * @return Process
     * @throws RuntimeException
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \LogicException
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    private function createProcess(): Process
    {
        if (!$this->cmd) {
            $phpBinaryPath = (new PhpExecutableFinder())->find();
            $this->cmd = [
                $phpBinaryPath,
                '-f',
                Path::makeAbsolute('bin/console', $this->kernel->getProjectDir()),
                '--',
                'app:processing:worker',
                '-e',
                $this->kernel->getEnvironment(),
                '-m',
                $this->getInput()->getOption('at-once'),
            ];
        }
        return new Process($this->cmd);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mcek It is actually pretty empty: `class StopCommandException extends \RuntimeException { public static function throw(): void { throw new self(''); } }`

Comment: It's been over 2 years and no better answer has come forward. This one seems workable though it's considerably more manual work than I had hoped, so I'm accepting it.